# Download app if intent not installed

Tags: android, download, android-intent

I know I have seen a way of calling an Intent, and if it doesn't exist the function will redirect to market for download the application that has the intent.

Right now I check if the Intent exists but I don't know how to point the user to the resource to download.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To check if some Intent is available:

```
String intentToCheck = "com.google.SCAN"; //can be any other intent
final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
final Intent intent = new Intent(intentToCheck);
List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
final boolean isAvailable = list.size() > 0;
```

To open Google Market via Intent:

```
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:com.google.scan"));
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

Comment: The second part is what I meant.

Comment: use `Uri.parse("market://details?id=<package_name>")` if you know the exact id of the app. You can find the id in your browser link when you are on the details page of the desired app in google play. [Doc](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this before but in theory it is just another Intent call with a view flag and the `market://...` URI pointing to the application.